# How to get Windows Ethernet settings from .net when cable is unplugged?

Tags: .net, windows, ethernet

1. Ethernet adapter is enabled.
2. Ethernet cable is unplugged.

If you change network settings to dhcp/static by Windows Settings or netsh than Windows Settings UI will show changes. But netsh and ipconfig will show old settings. My assumption is what Windows applies ethernet settings after cable is connected.

But must be place what stores new settings before cable is connected.
Can I access those new settings from .net? Or maybe it works not at all the way I think?

Comment: .NET does not re-implement the TCP/IP stack, it always pinvokes OS services to get the job done.  So what you see from the command line is what you'll see in a .NET program.

Comment: @HansPassant Sure. But OS stores those non applied settings until the cable is connected, maybe in file or registry, so maybe we can get it.